# Error on using Formik in react native expo app

Tags: react-native, formik

I am using formik in react native app using expo. Whilst using it on login form it is giving this error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: values

```
<Formik
      initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
      onSubmit={ values => {this.handleSubmit(values)}}
       >
            {formikProps => (
                    <>
                            <FormInput
                                name="email"
                                value={values.email}
                                onChangeText={formikProps.handleChange('email')}
                                placeholder="Enter email"
                                autoCapitalize="none"
                                iconName="ios-mail"
                                iconColor="#2C384A"
                            />
                            <FormInput
                                name="password"
                                value={values.password}
                                onChangeText={formikProps.handleChange('password')}
                                placeholder="Enter password"
                                secureTextEntry
                                iconName="ios-lock"
                                iconColor="#2C384A"
                            />
                            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                                <FormButton
                                buttonType="outline"
                                onPress={formikProps.handleSubmit}
                                title="LOGIN"
                                buttonColor="#039BE5"
                                />
                            </View>
                    </>
                )}
    </Formik>
```

why it is not recognizing values as I was following the tutorial accurately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not passing `values`, that's why you're getting that error.

change:

`{formikProps => (`

To:

```
{({formikProps, values}) => (
```

For more information, check the official documentation [here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/react-native).